# How to view vertical zoom in Sequencer with Python?

Tags: scripting, interface, video-sequence-editor

I know with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>middle mouse button</kbd> I can view vertical zoom , but how do I do this in python?

[image: Zoom vertically]

Comment: To be able to view the current settings, this needs to be done without operators.

For the 3d view, this information is held in, and can be set from 'context.area.spaces[0].region_3d' , but the space for the sequencer seems to have no equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will zoom in on the y:

```
layout.operator_context = "EXEC_REGION_WIN"
zoom = layout.operator("view2d.zoom", text="Zoom Y")
zoom.deltay=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is somehow connected to "bpy.ops.sequencer.view_ghost_border", but nothing happens when using that function(Click the "Zoom Y " button in the sequencer header menu):

```
import bpy

def MyFunction(context):
    if not bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor: #create sequence, if missing
        bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor_create()  

    bpy.ops.sequencer.view_ghost_border(gesture_mode=0, xmin=0, xmax=200, ymin=0, ymax=200)

class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator): 
    '''Tooltip for MyOperator'''
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"  
    bl_label = "My Operator" 
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"} 

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context): 
        if context.object != None: 
            return context.object.select
        return False

    def execute(self, context):

        MyFunction(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event): 
        return self.execute(context)

def menu_draw(self, context):

    self.layout.operator(MyOperator.bl_idname, "Zoom Y") 

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__) 
    bpy.types.SEQUENCER_HT_header.append(menu_draw) 

def unregister():
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_draw) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    register()
```